# Any ideas how to create auto-cutting file when it's size overflow some value?

Tags: dart

I have some primitive logger that writes information to file, but we have memory limitations with sending files to server, is there any practices to auto-cut file when it's size overflow some size value, for example, 2MB?

Comment: Track the file's size and when it reaches a certain threshold, stop writing to it and write to a new file.

Comment: @Abion47 this is not a good idea, because I need to save previous information

Comment: And what part of my suggestion would prevent you from doing that exactly?

Comment: @Abion47 this is expensive to write new file with something like copying information from previous file. I think that could be reached with some IO sink that can flush specific range of bytes.

Comment: Who said anything about copying the data from the previous file?